# Getting X-Cart Error Code 2 (missing class) when class exists

Tags: php, class, path, namespaces, x-cart

When trying to access my X-Cart project in the browser, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: "Includes\ErrorHandler::FATAL_ERROR" (code 2)
Class 'XLite\Module\QSL\Banner\Core\Database' not found
```

The full error is:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/src/var/run/classes/XLite/Module/QSL/Banner/Core/Database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /src/Includes/Autoload/StreamFilter.php on line 33

Fatal error: Class 'XLite\Module\QSL\Banner\Core\Database' not found in /src/var/run/classes/XLite/Core/Database.php on line 6
```

I've checked for the supposedly missing class file in my project. It's there with the proper namespace. I've tried clearing X-Cart's cache:

```
rm -rf src/var/resources src/var/datacache src/var/run/skins src/var/.lessFiles.php
```

I've also tried running `composer install` and `composer dump-autoload`. No dice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the cache did the trick:

```
rm -rf src/var/run src/var.rebuildStarted
```